# Specific for loop too slow in R

Tags: r

I have to use 2 data frames 2 million records and another 2 million records. I used a for loop to obtain the data from one another but it is too slow. I've created an example to demonstrate what I need to do.

```
ratings = data.frame(id = c(1,2,2,3,3),
                     rating = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     timestamp = c("2006-11-07 15:33:57","2007-04-22 09:09:16","2010-07-16 19:47:45","2010-07-16 19:47:45","2006-10-29 04:49:05"))
stats = data.frame(primeid = c(1,1,1,2),
                   period = c(1,2,3,4),
                   user = c(1,1,2,3), 
                   id = c(1,2,3,2), 
                   timestamp = c("2011-07-01 00:00:00","2011-07-01 00:00:00","2011-07-01 00:00:00","2011-07-01 00:00:00"))

ratings$timestamp = strptime(ratings$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stats$timestamp = strptime(stats$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

for (i in(1:nrow(stats)))
{
   cat("Processing ",i," ...\r\n")
   temp = ratings[ratings$id == stats$id[i],]
   stats$idrating[i] = max(temp$rating[temp$timestamp < stats$timestamp[i]])
}
```

Can someone provide me with an alternative for this? I know apply may work but I have no idea how to translate the for function.

UPDATE: Thank you for the help. I am providing more information.

The table stats has unique combinations of primeid,period,user,id.
The table ratings has multiple id records with different ratings and timestamps.

What I want to do is the following. For each id found in stats, to find all the records in the ratings table (id column) and then get the max rating according to a specific timestamp obtained also from stats.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't require a loop.  You should be able to essentially "embed" your definition of `temp` into the subset of `ratings` you want to use, and get the whole thing done with a single formula.  BTW, is it guaranteed that every element of `stats$id` can be found in `ratings$id`?  But some `ddply` expert will come up with a better method.  EDIT: use `pmax` in the vector formula

Comment: Please add a description of what you want to do. It's not easy to understand from your code.

Comment: And looking at `xts` and `zoo` is probably also a good idea for this kind of timeseries data.

Comment: And also your data frames have the same dimensions , why did you give an example with different siqzes (ratings /stats)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a data structure perspective it seems that you want to merge two tables and then perform a split-group-apply method.

Instead of for looping to check what row belongs to what row you can simply merge the two tables (much like a JOIN statement in SQL) and then perform an 'aaply' type of method. I recommend you download the 'plyr' library.

```
new_stats = merge(stats, ratings, by='id')

library(plyr) 
ddply(new_stats, 
      c('primeid', 'period', 'user'),  
      function(new_stats) 
      c( max(new_stats[as.Date(new_stats$timestamp.x) > as.Date(new_stats$timestamp.y)]$rating )))
```

If the use of plyr confuses you, please visit this tutorial: http://www.creatapreneur.com/2013/01/split-group-apply/.

Comment: what is the code behind `for`? do you think it is written in R? why loops are slow in R ?

Comment: I am getting an error with this: 
Error in attributes(out) <- attributes(col) : 
  'names' attribute [9] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: it worked on the example. now let me try it on the big dataset

Comment: I believe R is built ontop C, is it not? The native C code would have a for loop that is faster than that of R I would recon.

Comment: R is built mostly with C and FORTRAN (and R itself). What I object to is the notion that for loops in R are _inherently_ slower than one would expect. They are, in fact, quite fast. The problem, as I said, is that people make _other_ mistakes in their code in the process of writing a for loop that cause lots of excess copying. It is this copying of objects that slows things down, _not_ the for loop code itself.

Comment: This code using `ddply()` is actually _slower_ on my machine when run on the example 10000 times, than the OP's code using the plain `for` loop. I would be very interested to see how this performs on the OP's big dataset. But I rather doubt this can be made faster without using Rcpp...

Comment: Never use ddply for even largish data. data.table instead. Plenty of examples on SO.

Answer (score 6):

I love `plyr`, and most of the tools created by Hadley Wickham, but I find that it can be painfully slow, especially if I'm trying to split on an ID field. When this happens, I turn to `sqldf`. I usually get a speed up of 20x.

First I need to use `lubridate` because `sqldf` chokes on `POSIXlt` types:

```
library(lubridate)
ratings$timestamp = ymd_hms(ratings$timestamp)
stats$timestamp = ymd_hms(stats$timestamp)
```

Merge the dataframes, as Vincent did, and remove those violating the date constraint:

```
tmp <- merge(stats, ratings, by="id")
tmp <- subset(tmp, timestamp.y < timestamp.x )
```

Lastly, grab the max rating for each ID:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT *, MAX(rating) AS rating FROM tmp GROUP BY id")
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the ratio of `id`s to data points this may work better:

```
r = split(ratings, ratings$id)
stats$idrating = sapply(seq.int(nrow(stats)), function(i) {
  rd = r[[stats$id[i]]]
  if (length(rd))
    max(rd$rating[rd$timestamp < stats$timestamp[i]])
  else NA
})
```

If your IDs are *not* contiguous integers (you can check that with `all(names(r) == seq_along(r))`) you'll have to add `as.character()` when referencing `r[[` or use `match` once to create the mapping and it will cost you some speed.

Obviously, you can do the same without the split, but that's typically slower yet will use less memory:

```
stats$idrating = sapply(seq.int(nrow(stats)), function(i) {
  rd = ratings[ratings$id == stats$id[i],]
  if (nrow(rd))
    max(rd$rating[rd$timestamp < stats$timestamp[i]])
  else NA
})
```

You can also drop the `if` if you know there will be no mismatches.

Answer (score 3):

I voted the answer provided although I used another approach to get to the same result

In the merge dataset I first removed dates that were older than the conditioned date and then run this:

```
aggregate (rating ~ id+primeid+period+user, data=new_stats, FUN = max)
```

Comment: i did not know that this function existed. this approach is much more elegant, thanks for sharing!